# Electric field of a line of Charge on it axis using electric potential

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-fields, potential, classical-electrodynamics

We have a line of charge with length $L$ and charge density $\lambda$ and we want to find its Electric field on a point $p$ with distance $d$ from one end of it using potential.
I drew a picture like this and for voltage evaluated this integral
[image: y]

$$V =\int \frac{dq}{r}  = \int_0^L (\frac{\lambda dx}{(d+x)} = \lambda ~~ln(l+d/d)$$

and for Electric field (by substituting $x$ instead of $d$) we get:

$E = \partial V /\partial x = \lambda \frac{x-(l+x)}{x^2} \frac{x}{x+l}$ which is negative. But it actually should get positive because the Electric field is in direction of $+i$. What is my mistake?

Comment: $E=-dV/dx$, not $+dV/dx$.

Comment: Is the line of charge positive or negative charge? The field from $d$ to $P$ will be positive for positive charge and negative for negative charge since, by convention, the direction of the field is the direction of the force that a positive charge would experience if placed in the field.